# MySQL Find deliveryCompany that don't cover all zipCode

Tags: mysql, range, complex-numbers, zipcode

ZipCode range go from 1 to 99999 casted to int in MySQL

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+
+ deliveryCompany + minZipCode + maxZipCode +
+-----------------+------------+------------+
+       A1        +      1     +   99999    +
+       A1        +    15000   +   99999    +
+       A1        +    10000   +   17999    +
+       A2        +    5000   +     5009    +
+       A2        +    3000   +     5500    +
+       A2        +    7000    +   99999    +
+       A3        +       1    +    1000    +
+       A3        +     950    +   70000    +
+       A3        +   70001    +   99999    +
+       A3        +     700    +   99999    +
+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to get all deliveryCompany that don't cover all zipCodes (from 1 to 99999)

In previous example the results will be only A2 deliveryCompany

So I need to extract all zipCode range for any deliveryCompany then merge by union these ranges for the specific deliveryCompany and then verify that this merge have holes in range from 0 to 99999 (all zipCodes).

It's not immediate.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use any "gaps and islands" algo and combine the rows for each company into one, then check final ZIPs range. Recommendation - add a company with 2 ranges of (1,9999) and (90000, 99999) and a company with ranges (1,9999) and (10000,99999) into the source data for testing purposes.